# Showing HTML when JS says it should not be

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select that the shows the title property on load. I have some JS so that when certain options are selected different divs show. My issue is that the divs show on load and I don't want them to show until their correct option is selected.

```js
function typePicker() {
  var sel = document.getElementById("type");
  var manufacturer = document.getElementById("manufacturer");
  var model = document.getElementById("model");
  var typeInputs = document.getElementById("typeInputs");
  var aps = document.getElementById("aps");
  var cables = '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="cableType" placeholder="Type"></div><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"></div><!-- Quantity --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location -->';
  // Yes I know this is improper that is why I am doing the switch over and came across this issue

  if (sel.value == "aps") {
    aps.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    aps.style.display = 'none';
  }

  if (sel.value == "cables") {
    manufacturer.style.display = 'none';
    model.style.display = 'none';
    typeInputs.innerHTML = cables; // This line will be changed soon to the style above in process of doing this to all.
  } else {
    manufacturer.style.display = 'block';
    model.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Type of Asset" name="type" data-live-search="true" id="type" onchange="typePicker()">
<option value="aps">Access Point</option>
<option value="cables">Cable</option>
<option value="desktops">Desktop</option>
<option value="laptops">Laptop</option>
 <option value="deskPhones">Desk Phone</option>
<option value="mobilePhones">Mobile Phone</option>
<option value="monitors">Monitor</option>
<option value="printers">Printer</option>
<option value="projectors">Projector</option>
 <option value="routers">Router</option>
 <option value="switches">Switch</option>
  <option value="tablets">Tablet</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
     </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="typeInputs">
  <div id="aps">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" placeholder="IP Address">
    </div>
    <!-- IP Address -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mac-address" id="mac-address" placeholder="MAC Address">
    </div>
    <!-- MAC Address -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="range" id="range" placeholder="Range in M">
    </div>
    <!-- Range -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="textbox-n form-control" name="bands" id="bands" placeholder="Bands">
    </div>
    <!-- Bands -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="channels" id="channels" placeholder="Channel(s)">
    </div>
    <!-- Channels -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type=\'date\')" onblur="(this.type\'text\')" id="date-bought" name="dateBought">
    </div>
    <!-- Date Bought -->

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label for="poe">PoE</label>
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option1"> Yes</label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option2"> No</label>
    </div> <br><br>
    <!-- PoE -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type=\'date\')" onblur="(this.type=\'text\')" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate">
    </div>
    <!-- Warranty Date -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Location">
    </div>
    <!-- Location -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-gorup" id="warningType">

</div>
```

I can not get the snippet to work at all when you select another option. The only one there is code for in the snippet is for the aps and cables ones. Code works file on my server and is good enough for this snippet I believe. The main issue of the aps div showing upon load is the problem. How can I make it not show on load?

If additional code or info is needed please ask away.

Comment: Instead of snippet you may try http://jsfiddle.net or https://plnkr.co or whatever...

Comment: Just a note really but this seems like a good way to develop - show everything so that users without js get all content and then only if they have js should that content then be hidden and controlled by js. According to the priciples of unobtrusive javascript anyway. So, I just wish to warn against hiding them on load using CSS since users without js won't have an option to display them. Hide them on load using js.

Comment: @wunth I have multiple fields with the same name but for different models to save in your way would not work. Plus who doesn't have JavaScript anymore? Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge ect all gave it by default.

Comment: @joshkirby I'll take note that #aps{display:none} (your accepted solution) isn't possible in javascript. Also be aware that in order to show each section you'll have to once again show the containing div (using javascript) and manage the visibility of the individual divs within (which is what you should do in the first place). Google crawlers won't interact with you page to see content so it's also an SEO concern so not so much 'who' as 'what'.

Comment: @wunth the SEO is not an issue because this page will be behind a subscription paywall. Google can't get to it without a valid account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented what your question is asking for in CSS.

```
#aps {
  display: none;
}
```

This will hide you div with the ID of 'aps' by default, on load. You can then modify the style to display it when you need it.

```js
function typePicker(){
  var sel = document.getElementById("type");
  var manufacturer = document.getElementById("manufacturer");
  var model = document.getElementById("model");
  var typeInputs = document.getElementById("typeInputs");
  var aps = document.getElementById("aps"); 
  var cables = '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="cableType" placeholder="Type"></div><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"></div><!-- Quantity --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location -->';
   // Yes I know this is improper that is why I am doing the switch over and came across this issue

  if(sel.value=="aps"){
    aps.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    aps.style.display = 'none';
  }

  if(sel.value=="cables"){
    manufacturer.style.display = 'none';
    model.style.display = 'none';
    typeInputs.innerHTML=cables; // This line will be changed soon to the style above in process of doing this to all.
  }else{
    manufacturer.style.display = 'block';
    model.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
#aps {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Type of Asset" name="type" data-live-search="true" id="type" onchange="typePicker()">
            <option value="aps">Access Point</option>
            <option value="cables">Cable</option>
            <option value="desktops">Desktop</option>
            <option value="laptops">Laptop</option>
            <option value="deskPhones">Desk Phone</option>
            <option value="mobilePhones">Mobile Phone</option>
            <option value="monitors">Monitor</option>
            <option value="printers">Printer</option>
            <option value="projectors">Projector</option>
            <option value="routers">Router</option>
            <option value="switches">Switch</option>
            <option value="tablets">Tablet</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group" id="typeInputs">
        <div id="aps">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" placeholder="IP Address">
            </div> <!-- IP Address -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mac-address" id="mac-address" placeholder="MAC Address">
            </div> <!-- MAC Address -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="range" id="range" placeholder="Range in M">
            </div> <!-- Range -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="textbox-n form-control" name="bands" id="bands" placeholder="Bands" >
            </div> <!-- Bands -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="channels" id="channels" placeholder="Channel(s)">
            </div> <!-- Channels -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type=\'date\')" onblur="(this.type\'text\')" id="date-bought" name="dateBought">
            </div> <!-- Date Bought -->
            
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label for="poe">PoE</label>
                <br>
                <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option1"> Yes</label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option2"> No</label>
            </div>  <br><br><!-- PoE -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type=\'date\')" onblur="(this.type=\'text\')" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate">
            </div><!-- Warranty Date -->
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control"  id="location" placeholder="Location">
            </div><!-- Location -->
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-gorup" id="warningType">
      
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks didn't think of using CSS, was looking only at J's but you're right CSS will work good enough and likely is "better" depending on who you ask